# View page source Angular Universal with Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-universal

After user actions trying to update the script type application/ld+json src in angular Universal.

```
const script:HTMLScriptElement  = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'application/ld+json');
script.setAttribute('src', 'assets/data/bangalore-to-hyderabad-schema.js');  
this.dom.body.appendChild(script);
```

But in elements body section is updated not in view page source under body section. Any help?
thanks in advance.

Comment: `<html>
    <head></head>

    <body>
        <button onclick="updateScript()">click</button>
        <script type="application/ld+json" src="home.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    function updateScript() {
        var script  = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'application/ld+json');
        script.setAttribute('src', 'assets/data/bangalore-to-hyderabad.js');  
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean.. you want to add a script tag on a button click..? Is the script added dynamically when you inspect the rendered source? And you expect it to be in the source.. from the server..?

Comment: Default in index.html home-schema.js file added,
<script src="./assets/data/home-schema.js" type="application/ld+json"></script>
When user searches from to city  and user clicks on search button it will navigate to the car-rental/bangalore-to-hyderabad-one-way-car-rental
Now by using the above script it will update to the 
<script src="./assets/data/bangalore-to-hyderabad-schema.js" type="application/ld+json"></script>
this is working fine F12 elements under body tag but for SEO purpose it also need to update in the view page source under body closing tag

Answer (score 0):

It is normal. If you update dynamically the dom after a user action without reloading the page, then you will not see the modifications using View Source.

View source only shows you what the server sent to the browser, but none of the client side modifications